# Perl pipe hangs and process becomes defunct

Tags: perl, pipe

I have a perl script that executes another script using pipe:

```
$pid = open (OUTPUT, "my_script.pl 2>&1 |") || "";
if ($pid) {
  while (<OUTPUT>) {
    print;
  }
  close (OUTPUT);
}
```

`my_script.pl` forks another child process. When I first kill `my_script.pl` and then kill its child process (I kill the processes manually using `kill -9`), then `my_script.pl` process becomes a defunct and the pipe hangs.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

I don't want to kill the child process first.

Comment: Do you want `my_script.pl` to continue running even if you `kill -9 parent_script.pl` ?

Comment: I want the parent script to close the pipe when all the children scripts are killed... but the problem is that my_script.pl becomes defunct

Comment: Hmm - I don't understand what happens when. Can you please add a list/tree of which process starts which other process, and then tell us which process gets killed and when? I guess you want to move all processes into one process group so they all get killed together, but I don't understand your problem yet.

Comment: If "the pipe hangs", then some process still has the write side of the pipe open.  Post a process tree of all the processes that `my_script.pl` may have spawned.  At least one of them is still running.

Comment: What do you want to be able to do? To kill `my_script.pl` manually, from command line, while this script is running?  That's "rude" and you should expect that it may not work cleanly, precisely because `my_script.pl` may be tied up in something; so add a signal handler to it, in which you can clean up / close resources as needed.  If this isn't what you are after can you state the goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "the pipe hangs"? 1) Pipes don't do anything. 2) There is no pipe if you kill -9 the parent and the child.

Answer (score 3):

When a program exits, it becomes a zombie (defunct process) until its parent reaps it (by calling `wait`).<sup>[1]</sup> If the process disappeared entirely, programs wouldn't be able to get the exit code of child processes. This is entirely normal, and not a problem.

1. Orphans (including zombie orphans) get adopted by process 1, which immediately reaps its children as they finish.